Compare how close two covariance matrices resemble each other
Say that my model assumes vector $v_t$ has covariance matrix $\Sigma$. i.e $E[v_t v_t^T] = \Sigma$.
But the data I actually feed into the model has covariance matrix $\Omega$. i.e $E[ w_t w_t^T] = \Omega$. Here $w_t$ is the actual data of $v_t$. $v_t$ itself is not observable.
I want to evaluate how well my model assumption is. as in how well $\Omega$ resembles $\Sigma$.  Is there an existing method to evaluate that?

Your terminology is confusing: if the $w_i$ are "actual data," then what do you mean by their expectation?  And if you mean the expectation with respect to the model, then what distinguishes the $w_i$ from the $v_i$??  Are you perhaps trying to ask the question addressed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59446?

$w_i$ is the actual input to the model. $E[ w w_i^T ]$ just means the average of input.

More generally, there are different ways to compute matrix norms. You could use them to compute the norm of the difference between $\Sigma$ and $\Omega$.
In the context of model fitting and parameters estimation, a classically used metric is the Frobenius distance between matrices, as in the following paper (section "Evaluation metrics for learning of model parameters in numerical simulations"):
Sani, O.G., Abbaspourazad, H., Wong, Y.T. et al. Modeling behaviorally relevant neural dynamics enabled by preferential subspace identification. Nat Neurosci 24, 140–149 (2021). https://doi.org/10.1038/s41593-020-00733-0
Also note that in some context two matrices could have different values but similar properties (e.g. similar eigenvalues), which is relevant if you are trying to identify transition matrices in a dynamical system, see e.g. this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/591888/271601
